# PowerShell: Why I can't redirect stdout and stderr of external methods sometimes?

Tags: powershell, redirect, stdout, stderr

I have issues with redirecting output from non .NET assemblies method calls:

In the code below, you see one successful redirection with .NET class System.Net.Dns and two failed redirections.

One with an inline C# type and the other is a VS compiled .dll, which contains only the same content as the $cs_code codeblock.

My only workaround so far is to catch their output with [Console]::SetOut and [Console]::SetError.

> But why do they fail and how can I redirect/capture those stream
>   outputs ?

```
# .NET Version                   4.7.2
# PSVersion                      5.1.16299.431                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.431                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
# CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1    


if ($psISE) { cls }

$cs_code = @"
using System;
static public class demo
{
    static public void go()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("***Console.WriteLine***");

        Console.Out.WriteLine("***Console.Out.WriteLine***");
        //Console.Out.Flush(); // no effect here

        Console.Error.WriteLine("***Console.Error.WriteLine***"); // no output in ISE !
        //Console.Error.Flush(); // no effect here
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cs_code -Language CSharp

#[Console]::SetOut((New-Object IO.StringWriter))   # this would catch all stdout            
#[Console]::SetError((New-Object IO.StringWriter)) # this would catch all stderr

&{ [demo]::go() } 1> $null 2> $NULL              # no redirection, why ?

# &{ [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve('bla') } 2> $NULL # works as expected

exit 0


Add-Type -AssemblyName 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' `
         -ErrorAction Stop

Add-Type -Path "c:\_ClassLibraryDemo.dll" `
         -ErrorAction Stop

&{ [MyLib.Demo]::Go() } 1> $null 2> $null // no effect here
```

Comment: PowerShell engine know nothing about `Console.Out` or `Console.Error`, of course, it do not redirect them.

Comment: This is very similar to the situation with the current directory. There is the powershell engine's current directory/path, which can be set with Set-Location (alias cd) but there is also the current directory of the powershell process available via [Environment]::CurrentDirectory. .NET call involving files use process' current directory not the powershell engine's current directory.

Comment: @mikez: No, the issue here is in-process vs. external program, not PowerShell vs. .NET: using the `[Console]` API _in-process_ simply prints to the console, and
no other code in the same process - whether C# or PowerShell - sees that output, unless an explicit redirection is applied via the `.SetOut()` / and `.SetError()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- If you want to capture output from *in-process* code that produces output via the `[Console]` API, you *must* use explicit redirections via `[Console]::SetOut()` and `[Console]::SetError()`, the technique you mention in the question.
- See below for why that is necessary.

---

**PowerShell only allows capturing / redirecting the standard `stdout` and `stderr` streams of *external* (console) programs**, inside which, in the case of .NET-based programs, `Console.WriteLine()` and `Console.Out.WriteLine()` write to `stdout`, and `Console.Error.WriteLine()` writes to `stderr`.

When running in a console window, PowerShell passes an external program's stdout and stderr streams through to the console (screen) by default; by contrast, the ISE sends stderr output to PowerShell's error stream<sup>[1]</sup>.

`>` or `1>` redirects an external program's stdout (either to a file or to `$null` to suppress it), `2>` redirects stderr<sup>[2]</sup>.
Additionally, assigning output from an external program to a *variable* captures its stdout output, and sending an external program's output through the *pipeline* redirects its stdout output to PowerShell's success output stream.

---

By contrast, **you're using the `[Console]` type's output methods *in-process*, where no such capturing is possible**, because such method calls simply output to the same console that PowerShell itself runs in, without PowerShell knowing about it.<sup>[3]</sup>

You can cut out the middleman to verify this behavior:

```
PS> [Console]::WriteLine('hi')  *> $null # Try to suppress ALL output streams.
hi  # !! Still prints to the console - PowerShell streams were bypassed.
```

The only way to (temporarily) redirect `[Console]` output in-process is to explicitly call [`.SetOut()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?) and [`.SetError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.seterror), as mentioned in the question.

The reason that `2> $NULL` in `&{ [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve('bla') } 2> $NULL` *does* work is that the method throws an *exception*, which PowerShell outputs to *its error stream* (stream number `2`), whose output `2> $NULL` effectively suppresses.
Note that, because an *exception* is thrown, `2> $NULL` is only effective because the method call is enclosed in `& { ... }`; otherwise, the exception would terminate the redirection itself too.
However, with respect to in-process `[Console]` behavior with no exceptions involved, whether `& { ... }` is involved or not makes no difference.

---

Therefore, in order for your custom C# method to integrate with PowerShell's streams - short of using PowerShell APIs directly in your C# code - do the following:

- **use `return` for what should go to PowerShell's success stream** (stream number `1`)
- **throw an exception for what should go to PowerShell's error stream** (stream number `2`), but note that an unhandled exception will by default abort the enclosing statement as a whole.

---

Alternatively, **compile your C# code to an *external program***, say, `godemo.exe`:

```
# With an external executable, redirections work as expected.
godemo.exe 1> $null 2> $null
```

---

<sup>[1] This divergent behavior in the ISE is problematic; it is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996).</sup>

<sup>[2] If `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` happens to be in effect, any `2>` redirection unexpectedly causes a script-terminating error; this problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).</sup>

<sup>[3] The methods write to the current console's `stdout` and `stderr` streams, which, in the absence of an *external* redirection, print to the screen.</sup>

Comment: I've only wrapped the calls with &{  }, because it was used as workaround for similar issues.

Comment: @andiDo: Whether `& { ... }` is involved only makes a difference if an _exception_ is involved (`System.Net.Dns]::Resolve('bla')`, in your example); for `[Console]::WriteLine()`, ... calls it doesn't matter. Please see my update.

Comment: I didn't know about the exception capturing by in-process. **So Console.WriteLine() in an .exe would write to stdout but not when used in a .dll, right ?** I need it for log4net, which uses the console calls for internal debug messages and I wanted to capture them.Then I would need to capture with SetOut() and SetError() only for libraries. Good to know. Very nice answer, btw. **Thanks, mklement0**

Comment: I would say that `stderr` output will go to the PowerShell error (2) stream, except when in console and not redirected. The same is true for `stdout` output, if it not redirected (or piped) then it also go directly to console, but not to PowerShell output (1) stream. It is console host, whose behavior is different here, not ISE, IMO. But it is necessary evil, because otherwise PowerShell console host will not be able to support interactive console applications.

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl, I've reworded the answer. Given that it makes no sense to treat all stderr output as errors, I think it's better to consider the ISE's behavior the exception. I don't understand your point about interactive console applications.

Comment: @andiDo: An amended version of my previous comment: `Console.WriteLine()` _always_ writes to stdout, it's just a matter of who consumes / redirects it. When calling an .exe, PowerShell knows that that call will produce stdout and stderr output and allows you to capture / redirect it. In-process, such as via a .dll, `Console.WriteLine()` calls write to the stdout stream of the same console that PowerShell itself runs in, without PowerShell knowing about it.

Comment: @mklement0 *Given that it makes no sense to treat all stderr output as errors* I can not say, that I am happy how this part of PowerShell was implemented, and I have no intentions in arguing how `stderr` should really be processed, but this does not change that fact that ISE consistently pass all success and error output thru `Out-Default` to display results on ISE console, while console host make exceptions and sometimes patch `stdout` and `stderr` to the console directly, bypassing `Out-Default` and giving up ability to interpret `stderr` as an `ErrorRecord`, which create discrepancy here.

Comment: *I don't understand your point about interactive console applications.* If you always redirect (which you should do, if you want to pass everything thru `Out-Default`), then console applications will not see real console handle at their `stdout` and `stderr`, so you need to make exception here and patch them directly to console in some cases, if you want applications which need such handle to work properly. Note: you can not consistently patch `stdout` and `stderr` directly to console, as you not always have local console to patch to (graphical hosts, remoting, jobs).

Comment: Good info, thanks, @PetSerAl. Re stderr: there is no good solution, because PowerShell's error stream is truly just for _errors_, whereas stderr - despite its name - is not, so formatting non-error stderr output  like a PowerShell error  (multi-line, red) is unhelpful and confusing (leaving the debate about PowerShell's default error formatting aside - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3647).